# Detect touchesEnded in a view where touchesBegan is not called?

Tags: ios, swift

If a touch began in View A, then I drag my finger (I'm not dragging the view with me) over to View B, View B does not seem to detect touchesEnded, rather touchesEnded is run for View A. Is there a simple way to get View B to detect touchesEnded in this series of events without having to perform some search on points and views? I am drawing a line using the center of these two views.

Comment: Do the touch detection with the common superview of A and B.

Comment: That is how I am doing it now. My search, and consequential events, for the view where the touch ends seems to be a little buggy, but I think I will just have to create some extra properties on  the detectable views to limit the search.

Comment: "My search, and consequential events, for the view where the touch ends seems to be a little buggy" Then ask about that. Do you understand how to hit-test a point? Anyway, _this_ question turns out to be an x-y question; ask about what you are _really_ having trouble with, don't make up some fake solution.